# Changing specific appended xml element in python changes all appended elements

Tags: python, xml

Why after I append the xml object and I want to change it's children all the values are changed?

I want to copy xml element and change it's 'dd' value. Example input table:

```
<aaa>
    <bb>
        <cc>dd</cc>
    </bb>
</aaa>
```

I hoped following code would do the trick:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import copy

xml     = ET.parse('xml.xml')
root    = xml.getroot()

entity = copy.deepcopy(root[0])
for i in range(1, 5):
    print(i)
    root.append(entity)
    root[i][0].text = 'eee'+str(i)
xml.write('output_xml.xml')
```

I have hoped to see values eee1 to eee4, but unexpectedly for me I have received:

```
<aaa>
    <bb>
        <cc>dd</cc>
    </bb>
<bb>
        <cc>eee4</cc>
    </bb>
<bb>
        <cc>eee4</cc>
    </bb>
<bb>
        <cc>eee4</cc>
    </bb>
<bb>
        <cc>eee4</cc>
    </bb>
</aaa>
```

Running following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import copy

xml     = ET.parse('output_xml.xml')
root    = xml.getroot()

entity = copy.deepcopy(root[0])
for i in range(1, 5):
    print(i)
    root[i][0].text = 'eee'+str(i)
xml.write('output_xml.xml')
```

Corrects the output:

```
<aaa>
    <bb>
        <cc>dd</cc>
    </bb>
<bb>
        <cc>eee1</cc>
    </bb>
<bb>
        <cc>eee2</cc>
    </bb>
<bb>
        <cc>eee3</cc>
    </bb>
<bb>
        <cc>eee4</cc>
    </bb>
</aaa>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So my old friend has resolved the issue. The probem is that in python **everything is a reference** and in this case we end up all the entity copies referencing each other. To resolve this issue we need to change from:

```
root.append(entity)
```

to:

```
root.append(copy.deepcopy(entity))
```